# Angularjs Input date format short date

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

We return json from our services and we have a parser that converts these json dates to dates we can use and display. But id like to display just the short date - we dont need to show the time.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="DateOrdered"
                                   datepicker-popup="shortDate"
                                   show-weeks="false" />
```

id like to see - 11/11/2012 not 11/11/2012 3:00:00

I cant put a value on this input since im using ng-model. id like to not build some custom filter or directive - but i may have too - wondering if angularjs has something out of the box for this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `date` filter http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: How do you set `DateOrdered`?

Comment: Yes - dateOrdered is being set and displayed and the datepicker works and I can save - on load I just want to display the date not the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up building a custom date directive. date-format

```
ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function (valueFromModel) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(valueFromModel) || valueFromModel == "" || valueFromModel == null) {
        return valueFromModel;
    }

    var date = new Date(valueFromModel);

    var _date = date.getDate();
    var _month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var _year = date.getFullYear();

    return _month + "/" + _date + "/" + _year;
});
```